# After the latest update of Tor, I lost all bookmarks and it will no longer work

Tags: help

I am running an old laptop with Windows Vista and Tor worked fine up until the last update Jan. 25, 2018, I believe. After that the browser screen was different, all my saved bookmarks were gone, and it will no longer open any websites or close properly. The initial startup doesn't seem to have issues. I tried disabling my Bitdefender security, totally shredded and reinstalled Tor several times with the same results. Tor opens but will not work.  What am I doing wrong?  The update worked and caused no problems on my newer PC with Windows 10.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem and have tried similar steps. My desktop is running Vista 64 and I have Bitdefender. My Tor update came coincidentally at the same time as my Bitdefender subscription renewal, which resulted in an uninstall/reinstall of the software. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Same here. Ive tried different versions to no avail. Guess its time to upgrade to windows 7, then mine as well 10.